# Fitting a non-linear model where observations at each time are random variables drawn from a different (non-Gaussian) distribution

Tags: nonlinear-regression, gamma-distribution, stationarity

I have a non-linear (and not clearly linearizable) function of a few parameters that models a response over an independent variable (time):
$$
f(t;\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3).
$$
The function $f$ is the exact solution to a biological model that predicts an organism's response (over time) to series of predetermined stimuli. My research collaborators have run an experiment on each of $N$ organisms where observations are made at fixed time increments, so I'm presented with a data-set
$$
Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times T}
$$
where $N$ is the number experiments run and $T$ is the number of observations made in each experiment. Observations in $y \in Y$ are greater than or equal to zero, and I have good reason to believe (because of how the observations at each time $t$ are computed, and based on some QQ plots I've put together) that the observations at each time are drawn from a gamma distribution. I.E. for each time $t_r \in [1,T]$, we have $N$ observations $\lbrace y_{i r} \rbrace_{i=1}^N$ of an independent variable:
$$
X_r \sim \Gamma(k_r,\theta_r)
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the pdf of the Gamma distribution and $k_r$ and $\theta_r$ are the shape and scale parameters of the $r$-th distribution.

I am trying to find values of $\lambda_i$ that minimize some loss function so that
$$
f(t_r;\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) \approx y_{i r} \quad \forall i \in [1,N] \mbox{ and } \forall r \in [1,T].
$$

**Question:** Is there a standard approach to fitting the parameters $\lambda_i$ in this case? My ultimate goal is to use the parameters from multiple experiments for classification and/or some sort of concentration series analysis. More specifically, are there any glaring errors in the approach I describe below? I am a mathematician entering into the realm of biostatistics, so I could definitely use the advice of a good statistician! Everything I've found so far in the literature seems to assume either a linearizable model and/or Gaussian distributed noise.

**My approach so far:** My first approach was to try and minimize a loss function based on the sum of the log-likelihoods of the gamma distribution associated with observations at each time. The optimization problem was not stable for me, so I tried to break the analysis up a bit as follows.

1. For each time $t_r$ I have around 50 observations, enough I think to estimate the parameters $k_r$ and $\theta_r$ of the gamma distribution at that time. I do so by maximum likelihood estimation, so I have a set of parameters:
   $$
   \lbrace k_r,\theta_r \rbrace_{r=1}^T
   $$
   that specify the assumed gamma distribution at each time $t_k$ based on the observations.
2. Now I want to fit the parameters $\lambda_i$ to somehow minimize a loss function so that $f(t_r;\lambda_i)$ is close to the expected value of $\Gamma(k_r,\theta_r)$ at each $r\in[1,T]$. Recall that the expected value of a gamma distribution is specified by its parameters as $\mu = k\theta$. I've tried three approaches.

   a. I minimized the mean squared error of the difference between the fitted value of the model and the expected value of the distribution at each time point:
   $$
       \min_{\lambda_i} \sum_r \left(f(t_r;\lambda_i) - k_r\theta_r \right)^2.
       $$

   b. I thought that the above might not be consistent since the error is not normally distributed so I tried do something with the cumulative distribution function of the gamma distribution (call it $F(x;k,\theta)$). My thought is that I can use the CDF to infer the area under the gamma PDF between the expected value on the modeled value. I first tried minimizing the following:
   $$
   \min_{\lambda_i} \sqrt{\sum_r \left( F\left( f(t_r;\lambda_i);\theta_r,\lambda_r\right)-F\left(k_r\theta_r;k_r,\theta_r\right)\right)^2 }.
   $$

   c. I also tried what I did in (b), but in more of an $L_1$ fashion:
   $$
   \min_{\lambda_i} \sum_r \left\lvert F\left( f(t_r;\lambda_i);\theta_r,\lambda_r\right)-F\left(k_r\theta_r;k_r,\theta_r\right) \right\rvert.
   $$

The optimization in all three approaches above seemed stable... I'm leaning towards (b) based on what I think I know about the distribution of error. A few extra questions: Is this a reasonable approach? Is there a name for this? Am I missing something glaringly obvious to an experienced practitioner?

**UPDATE**

I've done a lot of digging on this, and my current approach is actually to find parameters that minimize the total deviance (the difference between the log-likelihood of the fitted model and the log-likelihood of a hypothetical saturated model). I'll write an answer up when I get a chance in the next week if there are no responses, but for now I'll hold off on answering my own question.

Comment: I do not understand why you need $f(t;\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$.  If you assume that $X_r \sim \Gamma(k_r,\theta_r)$ then that suffices for a model and all you need to do is estimate $(k_r,\theta_r)$.  What you are trying to do seems to reflect the method of moments  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics) where you minimize the distance between the theoretical moments and their empirical counterparts (if interested you should consider generalized method of moments (GMM) or GEE).  but it seems like you are introducing more parameters than necessary.

Comment: If you believe the response is a function of time as well, or that it is auto-correlated in time then you can deal with that by substituting the empirical moments for $(k_r,\theta_r)$ and estimating with GMM (similar to what you are doing) or you can impose a time series structure on $(k_r,\theta_r)$, such as $k_r = ak_{r-1} + v_r$ and $\theta_r = b\theta_{r-1} + w_r$.  In either case, it would probably be helpful to estimate $(k_r,\theta_r)$ independently first and examine the fitted values to see if any notable patterns exists.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld Regarding why we need $f$; I'll edit the question too, but in a nutshell we have a bunch of organisms and we are observing their response over time to a series of stimuli. There is a biological model (already in the literature) that fits the organisms' responses pretty well. $f$ is the exact solution to the model: a function over time parametrized by the $\lambda_i$'s. Maybe the method of moments could give better initial conditions for the global MLE problem I initially tried to optimize, but the equations won't be complicated and will still be non-linear.